# Getting text to go the entire width of a textarea in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, textarea

Please view the following fiddle in Firefox and you will see that the line of text in the textarea is getting cut off mid way through because of the long file name, but in IE and Chrome, the line goes the entire width of the textarea and only wraps once it has reached the end. I would like to achive this same behavior in Firefox and have tried everything I can with my limited CSS skills to make it work to no avail so thought I would stop pulling my hair out and come to the pros for some help.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yGuAy/1/

Comment: I'm using firefox and it works fine...

Comment: then you must have some version that does not exhibit the behavior I am talking about. I have version 13.0.1 and you can def see what I am talking about if you are using that version.

Answer (score 0):

No values of `word-wrap:` and `text-wrap:` seem to work for me. However, you can omit your problem by using dashes instead of underscores in links.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said I really cannot alter the file names because they must match the names of the files on the server (which are generated by a php script that I cannot access) so I have to stick with the underscores

Comment: You didn't mention that :p but ok, I see

Answer (score 0):

If you play around with the textarea width property and font-size you can reach a desirable outcome.

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yGuAy/57/)

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible and not really going to help because as I said I have no control on how long the file names are since these are user submitted files and I am not allowed to rename them.

Comment: But you can set the width of the textarea, can't you?    http://jsfiddle.net/yGuAy/1/

Comment: no it's set at it's maximum width already. I just used that size in the fiddle so you could see it without resizing the output pane. In the version I have the cols value is already set as high as I can set it and stay within the limits of the sites layout.

Answer (score 0):

By adding style of dimension in textarea it works-

```
<textarea cols="70" rows="3" style="width: 675px; height: 30px;">http://www.example.com/some_dir/another_dir/some_really_long_and_complex_file_name.ext</textarea>
```

But this is temporary solution but can not figure out why is it so with firefox.I think problem is with " / " in url .If i removes it works but same i don't know reason.

Comment: I just tried your exact example and could not see any difference. Here is a link with your exact code. Dabblet: http://dabblet.com/gist/3046720

Comment: Please go through this - http://jsfiddle.net/sandipkaranjekar/rkN32/ this work with me.I am using ubuntu firefox 4.0, if not works may browser issue.

Comment: Nope, still does not work using the link you posted. I am using Firefox 13.0..1 (latest public version) your version is quite outdated and many things have changed since then which is why it might work for you.

Answer (score -1):

I think the firefox is considering the last part of the string

```
/some_really_long_and_complex_file_name.ext
```

to be one single word (which is true), which may be longer than the horizontal space available in the text area, so it simply puts the the last part in the next line. So if you try increase the width of the text area it will fit horizontally.

Comment: Yeha, I know why it's doing it I just need to know how to make it NOT do it (with CSS if possible) since I cannot change the width of the textarea, nor can I change the size of the file names.